# Getting Datagridview Column Values to Textbox1, Textbox2,Textbox3

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, nested-loops

I tried every solution here. nothing works for me. I want to get values of a

```
 column("ProductCode")
```

to

```
 Textbox1, Textbox2,Textbox3....
```

here is as far as i got. this code displays data for the first row of the said column only. what i want to happen is after displaying the value of the first row of `"ProductCode"` to `Textbox1` it will display the value of the second row of `"ProductCode"` to `Textbox2`. Thanksss

```
    With DataGridView1
        For i As Integer = 0 To .RowCount - 1
            Dim x As UInteger

            For x = 1 To 12
                Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" + CStr(x), False)(0).Text = .Rows(i).Cells(2).Value()

            Next


        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have enough text boxes to accommodate all the rows, you only need a single `For` loop. You will notice that there is a blank row at the end of your Grid if you are allowing the grid to have rows added. In that case you will need `.RowCount - 2` to account for that extra row. The text box name will end with i + 1 because, although, the rows start with index 0, the text box name endings start with 1.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    With DataGridView1
        For i As Integer = 0 To .RowCount - 2
            Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" & CStr(i + 1), False)(0).Text = .Rows(i).Cells(2).Value().ToString
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```